# EclipseLink Connection Pooling handled in EntityManagerFactory or EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, eclipselink, connection-pooling

We have a OSGI enviroment, where we have several bundles with own persistance units and own JPA etities. In Every bundle we create a own EntityManagerFactory, leading to the problem that we possible habve multiple connection pools. What i am doing at the moment is to make a OSGI bundle which provides a single instance of a EntityManagerFactory to be used in all our bundles.

Where does eclipselink handle connection pooling? In the EntityManagerFactory or in every EntityManager created? Will it be enough to use the same factory to have a single connection pool for all bundles?

Is there a possibility to monitor the eclipselink connection pool(active connections, new connection created)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using Apache Aries RSA together with Eclipselink? It creates the EMF for you and you can use the connection pooling and XA support from pax-jdbc with it.

Comment: Internal  connection pools, setup by specifying jdbc.url in the persistence properties, are managed within a Session held by the EntittyManagerFactory.  You can also inject your own Datasources into an EMF http://onpersistence.blogspot.ca/2008/04/eclipselink-and-datasources.html  allowing it to be shared among different EMFs.

Comment: thank you for your hints, i am now using a single apache dbcp datasource in all entity managers